# simple mouseover issue with css/html

Tags: html, css

i'm new to html and css and I was wondering how I would go about creating a drop down img/box that has options in it. here is an example of what i'm talking about.

[image]

in this example, when you hover over the community button you get a list of options. Is there anyway of achieving this in css?

thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the demo of your code.............

Comment: you can do it better with help of `javascript/jQuery`

Comment: you can do this with javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: @diEcho javascript is completely unnecessary for dropdowns in most modern browsers

Comment: @djlumley Most of modern browser use javascript heavily even for the client side and you are saying its un necessary. may i know the reason?

Comment: @diEcho your own answer uses CSS and HTML, which is simpler and semantic too. There's very little reason to use javascript when semantic HTML and CSS will be more performant.

Comment: @djlumley Yes i ahve answerd with HTML/CSS but its too lengthy. if i have used with jQuery. it would be simplar.

Comment: HTML & CSS : Creates the styling. JS / JQUERY make it look pretty. Most people want pretty.

Comment: @diEcho - It's more semantic with CSS/HTML (i.e. more meaningful) and in terms of length you add about 2 lines of CSS ( `display:none;` as the default inner list state, and `display:block;` for the hover state).

Comment: @DavidBarker javascript frameworks like jQuery and Zepto don't add any "prettiness" to a site, they just make it easier to enable robust interactions (i.e. AJAX, client side MVC)

Comment: Agreed djlumley... but have you ever tried to animate DOM elements with CSS? Rhetorical question I know... hence why I wrote what I did.

Answer (score 1):

see this ( using CSS and HTML only)

#### HTML

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a> 
<ul id="subnavlist">
<li id="subactive"><a href="#" id="subcurrent">Subitem one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subitem two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subitem three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subitem four</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
ul#navlist { font-family: sans-serif; }

ul#navlist a
{
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#navlist, ul#navlist ul, ul#navlist li
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
}

ul#navlist li { float: left; }

ul#navlist li a
{
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #003366;
padding: 3px;
border: 1px #ffffff outset;
}

ul#navlist li a:hover
{
color: #ffff00;
background-color: #003366;
}

ul#navlist li a:active
{
color: #cccccc;
background-color: #003366;
border: 1px #ffffff inset;
}

ul#subnavlist { display: none; }
ul#subnavlist li { float: none; }

ul#subnavlist li a
{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
font-size: 8pt;
padding-top: 5px;
}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a
{
display: block;
width: 10em;
border: none;
padding: 2px;
}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a:before { content: " >> "; }​
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/c7xmU/)

[Reference](http://www.cssnewbie.com/easy-css-dropdown-menus/)

Comment: Alright guys, I looked at all of these links as well as many other ones but I just can't find what i'm looking for. Thank you all for trying to help, I actually learned some things :o. I think i'm going to just make it redirect to another page with an assortment of options as well as some pics so it's just not a plan page.

thanks again

PS: i'm posting on this comment cuz I can't answer my own question yet :/

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[30 Jquery animated drop down menus](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/drop-down-menu-30-free-scripts-to-enhance-header-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this page... [cssMenuMaker](http://cssmenumaker.com/)
there's several types of menus, pick the one you like the most and set the colors and style you like and download, images and css included...
Hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

list of mouse events html5  http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: You don't actually need to use any HTML5 mouse events, javascript, or anything else for _most_ dropdowns.